# Using "Sum" function when passing operation to SQL server via BizTalk map

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, biztalk

At the moment I'm sending an `XML` message to the message box, then in a map I have a element named `Operation` to map to `sql` server using the Select Operation on the table schema. Using the operation element I can state any column and receive a record in a response file. What I want to do though is use an aggregate function, such as Sum(Quantity) instead of Quantity to receive a total value of an entire column within the table.

Can this be done in a biztalk map?

Answer (score 1):

After searching and thinking about it, I found I could use the cumulative sum functoid on my response map.